# How to declare this specific object in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In plain javascript I have a var `_events` which is a dictionary of dictionaries of functions.

- All keys of dictionaries are strings.
- The functions are like: `function(info){}`

In TypeScript this is its definition:

```
interface MyCallback {
    (info: any) : void;
}
```

How can I declare events in a class? I have tried this

```
class MyClass {
    private _events: {string: {string: MyCallback[] }} = {};
}
```

However I get

> type '{}' is not assignable to '{string: {string: MyCallback[] }}'. property string is missing in type '{}';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
class MyClass {
    private _events: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: MyCallback[] }} = {};
}
```

So that type would allow something like this:

```
let events: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: MyCallback[] }} = {};
events["myKey"] = {};
events["myKey"]["myNextKey"] = [];
events["myKey"]["myNextKey"].push((info) => { console.log('callback'); });
```

Previously it was defining properties called `string`:

```
let events: {string: { string: MyCallback[] }};
events = { string: { string: []; }}
```